# Example on when to use didUpdateWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I think I understand all other `StatefulWidget` lifecycle callbacks, but `didUpdateWidget` is one that I never had to use, neither can think of a specific use case, as I just get information about the `Widget` using the `widget` getter at `build`.

So on which cases `didUpdateWidget` is useful and desired to be used?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`didUpdateWidget` exists for when you want to trigger side-effects when one of the parameters of your stateful widget change.

A typical use-case is implicitly animated widgets. These are implemented using `didUpateWidget` like so:

```dart
@override
void didUpdateWidget(MyWidget oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget.value != oldWidget.value) {
    // TODO: start a transition between the previous and new value
  }
}
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what's going on, indeed. But, in the end, this somehow helped me to solve a state-related side-effect problem that kept me busy for some two weeks.

Answer (score 4):

An example from the Flutter docs which implements `didUpdateWidget` can be found in [AnimationController docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html):

```dart
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Foo oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _controller.duration = widget.duration;
  }
```

Inside `didUpdateWidget`, the animation controller's duration (time remaining for animation) is replaced/ updated with the Widget's `State`'s duration.

Or from the docs itself:

> The duration of the controller is configured from a property in the Foo widget; as that changes, the State.didUpdateWidget method is used to update the controller.

I guess this means when `Foo` is **rebuilt with a new duration**, the animation controller is updated with this value, as opposed to being stuck with the duration that was set in `initState`, the original `widget.duration`.

**TLDR:** You can use `didUpdateWidget` to update `State` when a Widget get's rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's see what the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) will have to say on this:

> Called whenever the widget configuration changes. **If the parent widget rebuilds and requests that this location in the tree update to display a new widget with the same runtimeType and Widget.key, the framework will update the widget property of this State object to refer to the new widget and then call this method with the previous widget as an argument.**

Consider the following example:

```
 class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 const ParentWidget({super.key});

 @override
 State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

 class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
 int _counter = 0;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   home: Scaffold(
     floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
     onPressed: () {
         setState(() {
           _counter++;
         });
       },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: ChildWidget(counter: _counter),
     ),
    );
  }
 }
 
 class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChildWidget({
   super.key,
   required this.counter,
  });

  final int counter;

  @override
  State<ChildWidget> createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
 }

 class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  
  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
    debugPrint("initState method");
  }

 @override
 void didUpdateWidget(covariant ChildWidget oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

   debugPrint("didUpdateWidget Method");

   if (oldWidget.counter != widget.counter) {
    debugPrint(
      "The old widget with counter: ${oldWidget.counter}  was replaced 
       with new widget with counter: ${widget.counter}");
     }
   }

 @override
  void dispose() {
   debugPrint("dispose Method");
   super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  debugPrint("build Method");
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
     child: Text("${widget.counter}"),
    ),
   );
  }
 }
```

In the given example, when the Child widget is loaded first, only `initState()` and `build()` methods are executed, and `ChildWidgetState` is attached to the `ChildWidgetElement`.

When the floating action button is pressed, counter gets incremented, the `ParentWidget` is re-built and passes the updated counter value to the `ChildWidget`'s constructor. However, as the ChildWidget's `runTimeType` and `key` are the same, just `ChildWidgetState` is updated and the old `ChildWidget`(with counter value 0) is replaced with a new `ChildWidget`(with counter value 1).
See this [video](https://youtu.be/AqCMFXEmf3w?feature=shared) for detailed info.

This is what the change in the widget configuration means and this triggers the execution of 'didUpdateWidget()'.

The old widget was replaced with a new one and not updated like the State object because, in Flutter whether it is stateless or stateful, **a widget is immutable**. I hope, the name `didUpdateWidget()` makes some sense now.