# didUpdateWidget called immediately after initState in Flutter

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

According to `Flutter Documentation`:

> didUpdateWidget called whenever the widget configuration changes

But, in the following code, `didUpdateWidget` is called immediately after `initState` on the first time.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("initState called");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Test oldWidget) {
    print("didUpdateWidget called");
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}


// output
//
// initState called
// didUpdateWidget called
```

Can someone describe why this happens? and how can I compare the whole `oldWidget` with `widget`

Thank you

**update**
as @pskink mentioned, `didUpdateWidget` is not called immediately after `initState`, it's after the first build

Yet another question is why it is called after the first build with the following code:

```
    print("didUpdateWidget called");   <--
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);  <--
```

but if I call print after `super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);`, it works fine.

Comment: Hi. Please Copy & Paste the code in a flutter project and you see its called.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but why after first build `didUpdateWidget` is called? there is no change in the widget!

Comment: Yeah I already know that, but In this simple example there is not a parent widget, but `didUpdateWidget` is called.

Comment: You swapped the `print` line with `super.didUpdateWidget` and it works as expected. so it means anything before `super.didUpdateWidget` will run immediately after the first build. Thank you for your time and reply

Comment: JUST call the print first in your code in dartpad.dartlang.org and you see `didUpdateWidget` method is called after the first build

Answer (score 1):

In my test using Flutter 2.10.1 stable version, `didUpdateWidget` was only called after calling `setState()` to update the data displayed on the Widget. This behavior matches the description mentioned on the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) where the didUpdateWidget method is called whenever the widget configuration changes. After the didUpdateWidget method was called, `build` will then be called.

Here's how the flow can look like after calling `setState()` once.

1. initState()
2. build()
3. setState() called
4. didUpdateWidget()
5. build()

This can be replicated on this simple Flutter app.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    debugPrint('State initState');
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyHomePage oldWidget) {
    debugPrint('State didUpdateWidget');
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint('State Widget build');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter's widget life cycle, **always and only the `build()`** method is called after `setState()` and the `didUpdateWidget()` is called only when the parent widget is re-built forcing it to pass a new widget with the updated values in the constructor.

For detailed info with examples, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77660176/19368196).